# Unable to send sms based on sensor values with gps

Tags: android, gps, sms, accelerometer, sensors

I am developing a app which will send the sms based on the sensor condition.

Sms consists of gps location as well as the sensor value.

When I try it in emulator gps values became null and when I try it in mobile phone it showed an error. (application stopped like that)

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener , LocationListener {

    private SensorManager sensorManager;
    TextView xCoor; // declare X axis object
    TextView yCoor; // declare Y axis object
    TextView zCoor; // declare Z axis object
    TextView aCoor;
    public static float x;
    public static float y;
    public static float z;
    String theftreport;
    String Text;



@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{

    //for sensor 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    xCoor=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.xcoor); // create X axis object
    yCoor=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ycoor); // create Y axis object
    zCoor=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.zcoor); // create Z axis object

    sensorManager=(SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
      sensorManager.registerListener(this,sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);

    //for gps
   // super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener mlocListener = new MainActivity();
    mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {    }

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
 loc.getLatitude();
     loc.getLongitude();

     Text = "My current location is: " +"Latitud =" +
            " " + loc.getLatitude() +"Longitud = " + loc.getLongitude();

    // Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), Text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event){

    // check sensor type
    if(event.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER){
    // assign direction

        x=event.values[0];
        y=event.values[1];
        z=event.values[2];
        xCoor.setText("X: "+x);
        yCoor.setText("Y: "+y);
        zCoor.setText("Z: "+z);



        if(x>=5)
        {

        theftreport=Text.toString() + "Crash rate : " + x;

        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage("900XXXXXXX", null, theftreport, null,null);                                                       


        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "message sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
                                        }

}


@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
     Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Gps Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
}


@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Gps Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}


@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

Comment: @SList As his question says he develops an app which is obviously on Android platform. So you can add the tag as you have already attempted to edit his question.

Comment: did check gps permission in manifest file ?

Comment: yes i checked it Nadosh but still i am getting 0.0 as the value.. you now if i toast the values out side it working.. but when i use it to send sms it returns 0.0 as the value..

Answer (score 0):

When i had the same problem what i did was i made a public variable to store my location value and used that variable in the SMS sending class instead of calling the function.
Sorry to say i too don't know what is the exact problem.Since it was working i didn't try anything else.